# What is use of config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no") in JSch

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch, public-key

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();            
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
```

In above code why we need to set `StrictHostKeyChecking` value as `no` while connection to SFTP through JSch API?

Answer (score 10):

You should NOT set it actually. You lose much of the SSH/SFTP security by doing to.

The option tells the JSch SSH/SFTP library not to verify public key of the SSH/SFTP server. You are vulnerable to [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), if you do not verify the public key. Of course, unless you are connecting within a private trusted network (so you do not care for security/encryption).

Read about SSH/SFTP host keys:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_verifying_the_host_key

Answer (score 8):

StrictHostKeyChecking values: ask | yes | no

default: ask

If this property is set to **yes**, JSch will never automatically add host keys to the `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` file, and refuses to connect to hosts whose host key has changed. This property forces the user to manually add all new hosts.

If this property is set to **no**, JSch will automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts files.

If this property is set to **ask**, new  host keys will be added to the user known host files only after the user has confirmed that is what they really want to do, and JSch will refuse to connect to hosts whose host key has changed.

Comment: This is not completely accurate. What this answer says is the behavior of OpenSSH `ssh` client (and others like `sftp`). --- JSch does not implicitly use `known_hosts` file, unless you tell it to. Nor does JSch "ask" anything, unless you provide a code for the prompt.